# MYSQL Count group by rows ignoring effect of JOIN and SUM fields on Joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have 3 tables:

```
Orders
- id
- customer_id

Details
- id
- order_id
- product_id
- ordered_qty

Parcels
- id
- detail_id
- batch_code
- picked_qty
```

Orders have multiple Details rows, a detail row per product.

A detail row has multiple parcels, as 10'000 ordered qty may come from 6 different batches, so goods from batches are packed and shipped separately. The picked quantity put in each parcel for a detail row should then be the same as the ordered_qty.

... hope that makes sense.

Im struggling to write a query to provide summary information of all of this.

I need to Group By customer_id to provide a row of data per customer.

That row should contain

- Their total number of orders
- Their total ordered_qty of goods across all orders
- Their total picked_qty of goods across all orders

I can get the first one with:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) as number_of_orders 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY Orders.customer_id
```

But when I LEFT JOIN the other two tables and add the

```
SELECT ..... SUM(Details.ordered_qty) AS total_qty_ordered, 
SUM(Parcels.picked_qty) AS total_qty_picked
```

.. then I get results that dont seem to add up for the quantities, and the COUNT(*) seems to include the additional lines from the JOIN which obviously then isn't giving me the number of Orders anymore.

Not sure what to try next.
===== EDIT =======

Here's the query I tried:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  COUNT(*) as number_of_orders, 
  SUM(Details.ordered_qty) AS total_qty_ordered, 
  SUM(Parcels.picked_qty) AS total_qty_picked 
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Details ON Details.order_id=Order.id
LEFT JOIN Parcels ON Parcels.detail_id=Detail.id 
GROUP BY Orders.customer_id
```

Comment: Show us the full query you tried please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `COUNT(distinct Orders.order_id) as number_of_orders,`
as in

```
SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  COUNT(distinct Orders.order_id) as number_of_orders, 
  SUM(Details.ordered_qty) AS total_qty_ordered, 
  (select SUM(Parcels.picked_qty) 
    FROM Parcels WHERE Parcels.detail_id=Detail.id ) AS total_qty_picked 
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Details ON Details.order_id=Order.id    
GROUP BY Orders.customer_id
```

EDIT: added an other select with subselect

Comment: Ok, cool I can see why the COUNT should work with distinct, but for some reaon it always gives me '1' as number_of_orders.

Comment: Strange. Can you make sure there is more then one order_id by running again my answer (note that I edited the select and added order_id to the group by clause. Thx!

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had the wrong GROUP BY which was causing the error. Both of your solutions work. The SUM fields seem ok as well now, though I need to check them thoroughly. All very big numbers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, then I edit back the answer for fellow SO users, who will find this answer later ...

Comment: Ah. SO still a problem. If I do the first join then all is well with the numbers. But the second join causes the SUM on the first join field to we wrong. But the SUM on its own field is right.

Comment: So if I join Details, then SUM(Details.ordered_qty) is as expected. But if I join Parcels on to Details, then SUM(Parcels.picked_qty) is as expected, but SUM(Details.ordered_qty) is now returning a figure much too high. Obviously summing duplicate rows from the join... help!!

Comment: Ahh yes, I understand. Try added a second select to the answer, please try that (this uses subselect to avoid joining Parcels)

Comment: Yeah, that's the gist. I've solved it now with a subquery in the second join, so it joins a table just like the one youve made in your subquery. Seems to work now - I think its the same solution basically.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you feel the need to combine all these in one query?  Simplify by breaking it up in to separate queries, and if you want a single call to get the results, put the queries in a stored procedure, using temp tables.

Comment: There is a reason, yes. This query will itself be a View, and the app will run other queries using this view. This view will be emulating a data structure that will be available to the application in the future, but is not available yet. But the application needs to be developed now. So I need to use a View for now to bridge the gap between the old and new data structures while building the app.

Comment: If nothing else, you can always return the individual count/sum values as results from subqueries, which'd solve the parent grouping problem.

Comment: Yeah. Ive jsut solved it doing exactly that. Subquery to return the SUM for the 2nd Join.